# In VB.Net, What is this called --> �

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, character-encoding

Im looping through text files line by line and � this funny character pops up so much and when i import to MS SQL, that symbol causes loads of funny characters.

� <-- This is how VB see it in string. I copied it out of a string while running through code with a breakpoint.

That character pops up in string whenever it finds certain special characters in text file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Unicode Replacement Character, which is inserted instead of invalid Unicode characters. It has no special VB.NET name.

The most common cause is using an incorrect encoding when reading a file. You're probably reading it as UTF-8 now, but you need to change that to the actual encoding used by the file (likely Windows-1252 or something like that, but it depends on where the file comes from).

Comment: Since Dean mentions MS SQL, it could *also* be the result of trying to store unicode in a `varchar` rather than an `nvarchar`

Comment: @MarcGravell: varchar can't store a �; it would most likely end up as a ? in that case.

Comment: @DeanHart: Then give your StreamReader the correct encoding when creating it. The default constructor assumes UTF-8, and your file isn't - so you have to tell it the right value. There's no way for StreamReader to guess the correct encoding.